# Spring Boot 2 Hibernate save not always commiting

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, save

I've been updating from spring 1.5 to 2 and ran into this issue. I have the following two controllers with their dao. One saves to the database fine while the other does not. All my config is default spring.

```
// UPDATE ITEM
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/updateitem")
public String saveItem(Items item, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }

    try {
        itemsService.createOrUpdate(item);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return "error";
    }

    String url = "redirect:/menu/items?iditems=" + item.getIditems();

    return url;

}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/newextra")
public String newExtra(Items item, Extras extras, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }

    try {
        extrasService.createOrUpdate(extras);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return "error";
    }

    String url = "redirect:/menu/items?iditems=" + item.getIditems();

    return url;

}

// CREATE OR UPDATE ITEM
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public void createOrUpdate(Items items) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    session.unwrap(Session.class).save(items);
}


@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public void createOrUpdate(Extras extras) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    session.unwrap(Session.class).save(extras);
}

ITEM LOG
2019-01-08 10:10:43.023 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/updateitem", parameters={masked}
2019-01-08 10:10:43.024 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public java.lang.String com.paphos.pos.controller.MenuController.updateItem(com.paphos.pos.items.Items,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
Hibernate: select itemsextra0_.iditemsextrascat as iditemse1_9_, itemsextra0_.idextrascat as idextras2_9_, itemsextra0_.iditems as iditems3_9_ from itemsextrascat itemsextra0_ where itemsextra0_.iditems=0 order by itemsextra0_.idextrascat asc
Hibernate: select categories_.idcategories, categories_.name as name2_3_ from categories categories_ where categories_.idcategories=?
Hibernate: insert into items (idcategories, description, hidden, name, price, upc) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-01-08 10:10:43.054 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND


EXTRAS LOG
2019-01-08 09:54:24.316 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/newextra", parameters={masked}
2019-01-08 09:54:24.316 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public java.lang.String com.paphos.pos.controller.MenuController.newExtra(com.paphos.pos.items.Items,com.paphos.pos.extras.Extras,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
Hibernate: select extrascat_.idextrascat, extrascat_.description as descript2_7_, extrascat_.name as name3_7_ from extrascat extrascat_ where extrascat_.idextrascat=?
2019-01-08 09:54:24.356 DEBUG 10228 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
```

Creating new items works but creating new extras does not. It runs a select query on the table but does not insert anything. Any ideas? I believe it may have something to do with transactions. I have my classes with @Transactional from spring framework.

UPDATE
I'm getting a transaction error when trying to run a delete.
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query   but, looking at my logs my transaction manager is running

Comment: Can you post your service and controller classes with their annotations?

Is your concrete implementation of the ExtrasService or the interface annotated? Spring recommends to use `@Transactional` only on concrete instances - see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: My DAO classes are annotated. I solved my issue after looking more into my code. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around at the differences in my code I found my error. For my Extras object I did not have the @GeneratedValue annotation and this was causing the issue. You need this annotation even if your table is set to auto increment which used to not be the case. Weird that I did not receive an error for this because if you have the annotation without auto increment set in db than you get an error for the id.. I'm using mysql btw